# What does crontab do when I give no argument?

Tags: linux, cron, arguments

I accidentally typed this command without any arguments and hit enter, and it seems the terminal is running something, so my question is what crontab do when I give no arguments?

`[root@localhost ~]# crontab`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`crontab` with no arguments reads a new `crontab` from standard input, validates it, and then replaces the current user’s `crontab` with it.

To get out of your situation, without losing your existing `crontab` (if any), either kill `crontab` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, or enter an invalid cron job definition (`foo`) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>:

```
foo
# Now press Ctrl+D
"-":1: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
```